# Clustering, Large dataset, learning large number vocabulary words

Tags: matlab, bigdata, cluster-analysis

I am try to do clustering from a large dataset dim: 
**rows: 1.4 million
cols:900**

**expected number of clusters: 10,000 (10k)**

Problem is : s**ize of my dataset 10Gb, and I have  RAM of 16Gb**. I am trying to implement in Matlab. It will be big help for me if someone could response to it.

P.S. So far i have tried with hierarchical clustering. in one paper, tehy have suggested to go for "***fixed radius incremental pre-clustering"***. But I didnt understand the procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **I am trying to implement in Matlab.** Why `python` tag ?

Comment: thank you for your response. If i know the algorithm, then i believe, i can implement in python as well.

Comment: I assume each datapoint takes up about 8 bytes, since `(1.4E6*900*8)/(10*2^30)` is close to one, but that is not enough information for me to help you. What kind of data do you have? text, numbers? You have 900 parameters for 1.4 million events? Please clarify your problem, post what you have code so far, and post a few of the rows for people to test their answers on.

Answer (score 0):

Use some algorithm that does *not* require a distance matrix. Instead, choose one that can be index accelerated.

Anuthing with a distance matrix will exceed your memory. But even when not requiring this (e.g., SLINK uses only O(n) memory) it still may take too long. Indexes could reduce the runtime to O(n log n) although  on your data, indexes may have problems.

Index accelerated algorithms are for example: OPTICS, DBSCAN.

Just don't use the really bad Matlab scripts for these algorithms.

Comment: Thank you,  for your suggestions. Somehow i have managed to do that.